# mstest, how to run all tests automatically?

Tags: mstest

The metest.exe can be used to run a test given a testcontainer parameter (DLL file). How can I run all tests (just like select [test]->[run]->[all tests] in Visual Studio) automatically in all solution?

Comment: You could try a piece of powershell to construct the command: `"mstest.exe /testcontainer:" + (((dir *.dll) | %{"'$_'"}) -Join " /testcontainer:")`

Answer (score 0):

When running mstest from the command line you need to provide mstest with information on where to find the test. This is done by proving a container of a meta data file.

> Because the test metadata file also lists tests that you can run, you
>   must not specify both the /testcontainer and /testmetadata options in
>   a single command line. Doing this would be ambiguous and would produce
>   an error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx